# using mongoose's ObjectId for authorization

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, mongoose, jwt

Would it be good practice to use the ObjectId generated by mongoose as a way of checking if data belongs to a certain user?

Example sudo code:

Example in db:

```
[ObjectId]: {
     myStuff: 'foo'
}
```

Example checking authorization:

```
if (jwt.bar.ObjectId === ObjectId) {
     //then you can mod this data because it is yours
}
```

If not, what is a recommended way of approaching this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB ObjectID safe for session id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263985/mongodb-objectid-safe-for-session-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the ObjectID as a session identifier, because it is never renewed once the document is created, and it is predictable.

From [MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/):

> The 12-byte ObjectId value consists of:
>
> a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
>
> a 3-byte machine identifier,
>
> a 2-byte process id,
>
> and a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

From a security's perspective, it would be a bad practice.

Use proper sessions IDs to identify requests coming from users.

Comment: @thanks. Would it be a good idea to use something like NPM's 'uniqid' to generate a UID then save it under a user's profile to use for the same propose?